# use quotes in sql query node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have my query like so:

```
let thequery = "insert into USERS (USERNAME) VALUES ('" + username + "')"
```

but when I insert the query into my database (I am storing the query for analytical purposes), it fails because of the quotes.

```
var insertAnalyticsLogin = "insert into ANALYTICS (username, location, device, query, timeoflogin) VALUES ('" + username + "', '" + location + "', '" + device + "', '" + thequery + "', '" + timeoflogin + "')"
```

how can I fix this? I tried converting `thequery` to `toString()`, but that was a useless attempt. Any other ideas?

edit:

error i am recieving is:

```
    sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'email@email.com')', '1/5/2022, 11:32:54 AM')' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "insert into ANALYTICS (username, location, device, query, timeoflogin) VALUES ('email@email.com', 'n/a', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15', 'insert into USERS (USERNAME) VALUES ('email@email.com')', '1/5/2022, 11:32:54 AM')"
```

Comment: It depends on which MySQL connection library you're using. **Any** of them will show examples of how to do parameterized queries quite prominently in their documentation, because of the [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) problem. (Building SQL by inserting values using string concatenation is almost always poor practice at best, and likely an attack vulnerability.)

Comment: @RyanWilson just updated. I can show my entire function if necessary

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how would I check which conn library i am using?

Comment: Look at your `package.json`, and/or ask the member of your team who set things up.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is the only thing I see in the `package.json`. `"mysql": "^2.18.1",`

Comment: That tells you you're using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: @roger I think your issue may be from this: `'insert into USERS (USERNAME) VALUES ('email@email.com')'` Since you are storing this value as a varchar (string), you need to escape the inner single quotes. Try changing to: `'insert into USERS (USERNAME) VALUES (''email@email.com'')'`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you, this article cleared a few things up for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great example of how using parameterized queries is better than using string-concatenation to format SQL queries. You can use parameter placeholders and then you never have to worry about the possible literal quote characters in your string variables.

```
var insertAnalyticsLogin = "insert into ANALYTICS (username, location, device, 
  query, timeoflogin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

mysqlconn.query(insertAnalyticsLogin, 
  [username, location, device, thequery, timeoflogin],
  function(err, rows) {
    ...
```

You don't even need the single-quotes around the `?` placeholders. In fact, you must not quote the placeholders, or else it will try to insert a literal string "?" instead of treating it as a parameter.

Using query parameters makes your code easier to read and easier to write, without getting eyestrain trying to balance all those quotes-within-quotes.

Comment: this worked thank you! this is much cleaner and actually makes more sense. BTW, does use query parameters increase security in terms of vulnerability to sql injection?

Comment: @roger - It does **if** the library you're using sanitizes them correctly when you do. That depends on the library. That `mysql` lib does.

Comment: oh okay fantastic. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and expertise with me :) @T.J.Crowder